# MySQL/Postgres: LAST_INSERT_ID() / LASTVAL() different behaviour

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a simple trigger setup both in mysql and postgres.

This trigger inserts a row in a logging table when a row is inserted in the main table.

When I now insert a row in the main table, mysql / postgres shows a different behaviour, if I call one of the following functions afterwards:

- `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`: returns the id of the row in the **main** table
- `SELECT LASTVAL()`: returns the id of the row in the **logging** table

Is this intentional and a reliable behaviour?

Comment: In PostgreSQL You should use trigger's predefined variable `NEW`, which holds the complete inserted row, including the new `id`. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html I beleive MySQL has something similar.

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() / LASTVAL() are not called inside the trigger. They are called outside. I updated the question to be more precise.

Comment: Postgersql and MySQL are two different products with different implementations. Asking for consistency between two products in a non-standard feature, is a bit too much of an expectation.

Comment: Also, do not forget that last_insert_id() works with auto increment fields. If the table does not have such a field, then last_insert_id() can't return any values from that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is by design and obviously intentional.

[image]
[image]